# St. Faustina on the measure of the love of God in the soul

Tags: catholicism, love, meaning, st-faustina

In [entry **(774)** of her Diary](http://www.seraphim.my/divinemercy/diary/text/DiaryII(751-800).htm), *Divine Mercy in My Soul*, St. Faustina writes:

"... in the spiritual life, suffering is the thermometer which measures the love of God in a soul."

The complete entry is:

> **(774)** *+* O my Jesus, I understand well that, just as illness is measured with a thermometer, and a high fever tells us of the seriousness of the illness, so also, in the spiritual life, suffering is the thermometer which measures the love of God in a soul.

QUESTION: Does the "love of God" refer to God's Love for the soul, or the soul's love for God? Or something else? Does anyone know, with a fair degree of confidence, what St. Faustina means by this statement?

*Remark:* She had previously noted in [**(343)**](http://www.seraphim.my/divinemercy/diary/text/DiaryI(301-350).htm) that: "True love is measured by the thermometer of suffering."